# execCommand("insertHTML", ...) in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm building a wysiwyg-editor with an editable iframe using `document.execCommand()`. Now i need to use the `"insertHTML"` command which works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox but of course it doesn't work in Internet Explorer:

```js
function run() {
  document.getElementById("target").focus();
  document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<b>ins</b>");
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable id="target">contenteditable</div>
<button onclick="run()">contenteditable.focus() + document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "&lt;b>ins&lt;/b>")</button>
```

What is the standard solution to this problem? It's okay if it only works in IE8 but IE7-support would be nice too.

Comment: [These](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7536602/) [bug reports](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/issues/771#issuecomment-182233090) imply that Edge supports execCommand("insertHTML", ..) (though with its own quirks).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In IE <= 10 you can use the `pasteHTML` method of the `TextRange` representing the selection:

```
var doc = document.getElementById("your_iframe").contentWindow.document;

if (doc.selection && doc.selection.createRange) {
    var range = doc.selection.createRange();
    if (range.pasteHTML) {
        range.pasteHTML("<b>Some bold text</b>");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

In IE 11, `document.selection` is gone and `insertHTML` is still not supported, so you'll need something like the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6691294/96100

Comment: IE seems to be adding the text to the very top of the page. Any idea why it's not being placed in the iframe specified by var doc?

Comment: @tundoopani: Not without more context. Do you have an example page?

Comment: I coded a simple version here: http://jsfiddle.net/MWz7A/3/. In IE9, the content is not placed in the iframe editor.

Answer (score 3):

In case you haven't found anything yet,

I had a button that would add html into an iframe, and was causing an error in IE8 when I clicked the button and no text was selected (i.e. when I had the blinking caret).  It turned out that the button itself was getting selected (despite having unselectable="on"), and causing javascript to throw up the error.  When I changed the button to a div (with unselectable on) it worked fine, in IE8 and FF.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is extremely old, but since IE is still a problem, here is a better way which does not even use `execCommand`.

This is missing some checks, like ensuring you're in the right container to be adding an image.

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var img = document.createElement("img");
// add image properties here

frag.appendChild(img);
range.insertNode(frag);
```

Comment: Even this issue being old, this answer is the only one that worked for me. Thanks by sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @dexiang The easy option is to not care about IE8 and below. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var doc = document.getElementById("your_iframe").contentWindow.document;

// IE <= 10
if (document.selection){
    var range = doc.selection.createRange();
        range.pasteHTML("<b>Some bold text</b>");

// IE 11 && Firefox, Opera .....
}else if(document.getSelection){
    var range = doc.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var nnode = doc.createElement("b");
        range.surroundContents(nnode);
        nnode.innerHTML = "Some bold text";
};
```

Comment: Method `pasteHTML` doesn't exist on `range` object, in my IE9

Comment: To those with the same issue, the [@David answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27642361/3136474) is the only one that worked for me.