# get a clickable link from a selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, execcommand

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    let selection = document.getSelection().toString().trim();
  document.execCommand('createLink', true, selection);
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class = 'parent' contentEditable = 'true'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet google.com
</div>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

So make a selection from `google.com` and click the button.

`google.com` becames blue as it is a link, but click on it - doesn't work.

How to get a real clickable link from `google.com` with target = `_blank`, and cursor = `pointer`, if possible?

Comment: Because of content editable it will work as an editor, you can have 2 modes preview and editor both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a target="\_blank" with execCommand 'createlink'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811132/adding-a-target-blank-with-execcommand-createlink)

Comment: @Justcode, `you can have 2 modes...` could you explain a bit, pls, or give me a reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/rfy5hz8q/13/

working fiddle:

```
(function($){
    $('button').on('click', function(){
       let selection = document.getSelection().toString().trim();
       document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<a contentEditable="false" 
       href="' + selection + '" target="_blank">' + selection + '</a>');    
    })

})($)
```

Comment: The last thing to add is to http at the begginig of such link.

Answer (score 0):

Links wrapped in an element that has `contentEditable='true'` will not work, because they are basicaly inside a "text editor".

Maybe you should try changing the `contentEditable` attribute on click so that it is set at `false` when the text is not focused / clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Content editable works same as the you are working in any editor, get an example of stackoverflow editor,one way is to have editor and preview both, something like this.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    let selection = document.getSelection().toString().trim();
  document.execCommand('createLink', true, selection);    
})
$("#preview").on('click', function(){
 var value = $('.parent').attr('contenteditable');

    if (value == 'false') {
        $('.parent').attr('contenteditable','true');
        $('#preview').text("Preview")
    }
    else {
        $('#preview').text("Edit")
        $('.parent').attr('contenteditable','false');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class = 'parent' contentEditable='true'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet google.com
</div>


<br>
<button>CLICK</button><button id="preview">Preview</button>
```