# InsertHTML support in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I want to insert some html into the page.

```
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, "<a href=\""+ url + trackingParam + "\">"+ url + "</a>")
```

This command works fine in Chrome. But, I did some search, it seems like `insertHTML` is not supported by IE 11.

I am wondering if there is a equivalent solution for IE 11.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398378/execcommandinserthtml-in-internet-explorer

Comment: Could always do `document.body.innerHTML += 'more html'`

Comment: @Taplar Thanks! I tried your comment, but it doesn't work. Your command is not equivalent with mine, It will insert the content to the outside of the div...

Comment: If you want it in the div, then you just need to select the div first, then do the innerHTML += off of that.  https://jsfiddle.net/e29z1pow/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [execCommand("insertHTML", ...) in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398378/execcommandinserthtml-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: @Taplar, I find that your suggestion can solve the issue. I suggest you to post your solution as an answer.